# opencv library installation on windows

Tags: windows, git, opencv, installation

I found  this project on github that requires the opencv library. The author has given the following instruction for linux and osx but none for windows:

I tried using the linux commands on windows but it gave me an error at `cmake`, saying 
`cmake command not found`. So i downloaded `cmake` and tried running it again it still continues to give the same error.

Can someone advise on how to get this working? Or point me to some other way to install the library?

---

### OSX

```
cd ~
git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4.5
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

### Linux (Tested on Ubuntu 12.04)

```
cd ~
git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4.5
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

## Compiling PuzzleSolver

Once the opencv library has been installed, you can try to open the xcodeproject, or on linux or mac run this from the PuzzleSolver directory (with the source files):

```
g++ -O3 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o PuzzleSolver *.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

This will result in an executable called PuzzleSolver.

Comment: If you downloaded `cmake` but still get the "not found" error, you probably need to get the downloaded `cmake` in your path somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just get the [binary pack](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.8/opencv-2.4.8.exe/download) [~400mb]